# Как сделать обязательным к выбору один из вариантов радио кнопок

Tags: javascript

```js
let a;

function example() {
  for (var i = 1; 1 < 7; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById(i).checked) {
      a = document.getElementById(i).value
      alert('Вашим браузером является - ' + a)
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Каким браузером вы пользуетесь?</h1>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="browser" id='1' value='IE'>Internet Explorer<br>
  <input type="radio" name="browser" id='2' value='Mozilla'>Mozilla<br>
  <input type="radio" name="browser" id='3' value='Opera'>Opera<br>
  <input type="radio" name="browser" id='4' value='Chrome'>Chrome<br>
  <input type="radio" name="browser" id='5' value='Yandex'>Yandex<br>
  <input type="radio" name="browser" id='6' value='Tor'>Tor<br>
  <input type="submit" onclick="example()" style=margin:5px;><input type="reset" name="">
</form>
```

Вопрос в следующем: как сделать так, чтобы если я не выбрал не 1 из радио батонов, мне выдавало ошибку?

Answer (score 1):

попробуй внутри первого `<input>` написать `required`.

```js
let a;

function example() {
  for (var i = 1; 1 < 7; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById(i).checked) {
      a = document.getElementById(i).value
      alert('Вашим браузером является - ' + a)
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Каким браузером вы пользуетесь?</h1>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="browser" id='1' value='IE' required>Internet Explorer<br>
  <input type="radio" name="browser" id='2' value='Mozilla'>Mozilla<br>
  <input type="radio" name="browser" id='3' value='Opera'>Opera<br>
  <input type="radio" name="browser" id='4' value='Chrome'>Chrome<br>
  <input type="radio" name="browser" id='5' value='Yandex'>Yandex<br>
  <input type="radio" name="browser" id='6' value='Tor'>Tor<br>
  <input type="submit" onclick="example()" style=margin:5px;><input type="reset" name="">
</form>
```

Comment: все изменил код проверь здесь должен работать

Comment: спасибо , выручил:)

Comment: @vegaszce, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers